# MongoDB: F CONTROL [main] Failed global initialization: FileNotOpen: Failed to open "/data1/mongodb/log/mongod.log"

Tags: mongodb, configuration, mongodb-3.4, redhat

I am trying to install mongodb 3.4 on Redhat 7.9. When I start mongodb `systemctl start mongod` I get the below error `FileNotOpen: Failed to open "/data1/mongodb/log/mongod.log`, But when I start mongodb manually **I don't see** any issue  `mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf`.

from `/data1/mongodb/log/mongod.log` I see this error, not sure why it's saying `/data/db/mongod.lock`

```
2021-05-21T15:10:40.688-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1434 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=gcppaadmdb01.liverpool.com.mx
2021-05-21T15:10:40.688-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.24
2021-05-21T15:10:40.688-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 865b4f6a96d0f5425e39a18337105f33e8db504d
2021-05-21T15:10:40.688-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
2021-05-21T15:10:40.688-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2021-05-21T15:10:40.688-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2021-05-21T15:10:40.688-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2021-05-21T15:10:40.688-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: rhel70
2021-05-21T15:10:40.688-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2021-05-21T15:10:40.688-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2021-05-21T15:10:40.688-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { processManagement: { fork: true }, systemLog: { destination: "file", path: "/data1/mongodb/log/mongod.l
og" } }
2021-05-21T15:10:40.689-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock Resource temporarily unavailable. Is a mo
ngod instance already running?, terminating
2021-05-21T15:10:40.689-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2021-05-21T15:10:40.689-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2021-05-21T15:10:40.689-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2021-05-21T15:10:40.689-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
[root@gcppaadmdb01 ~]# ls -lrt /data/db/mongod.lock
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mongod mongod 0 May 24 21:18 /data/db/mongod.lock
```

**Before error**

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-05-20 23:38:54 CDT; 3min 14s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 3698 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 3694 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3690 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3687 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 20 23:38:54 mongodb.test.com systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
May 20 23:38:54 mongodb.test.com mongod[3698]: 2021-05-20T23:38:54.076-0500 F CONTROL  [main] Failed global initialization: FileNotOpen: Failed to open "/data1/mongodb/log/mongod.log"
May 20 23:38:54 mongodb.test.com systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 20 23:38:54 mongodb.test.com systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
May 20 23:38:54 mongodb.test.com systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
May 20 23:38:54 mongodb.test.com systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
```

Permissions on /data1/ folder looks good

```
[root@mongodb]# ls -l /data1/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x. 4 mongod mongod  4096 May 20 23:38 mongodb
[root@mongodb]# ls -l /data1/mongodb/log/mongod.log                                                                                                                                          
-rw-r--r--. 1 mongod mongod 3846 May 20 23:42 /data1/mongodb/log/mongod.log
```

**mongod.conf** file
[root@mongodb]# cat /etc/mongod.conf
storage:
dbPath: /data1/mongodb/data
journal:
enabled: true

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /data1/mongodb/log/mongod.log

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

**System service** file

```
[root@mongodb]# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service 
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Server
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongod
Group=mongod
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /etc/mongod.conf"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb
PermissionsStartOnly=true
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
Type=forking
LimitFSIZE=infinity
LimitCPU=infinity
LimitAS=infinity
LimitNOFILE=64000
LimitNPROC=64000
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that ownership of that log file is not the real problem here.
Missing /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid -file is.

Your mongod.service file describes "PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid", but in your /etc/mongod.conf file the is no

```
processManagement:
  fork: true
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongod/mongod.pid
```

When you say "systemctl start mongod.service", it will start mongod, but it will kill the process after 5 seconds, because it cannot find that pid-file.

Comment: I made changes to `mongod.conf` as per your suggestions. now I don't see the permission, but the service is still not up. I see below the error

Comment: ```May 23 23:14:25 mongodb.test.com mongod[7794]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.

May 23 23:14:25 mongodb.test.com mongod[7794]: forked process: 7796
May 23 23:14:25 mongodb.test.com mongod[7794]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1
May 23 23:14:25 mongodb.test.com systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 23 23:14:25 mongodb.test.com systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.```

Comment: Please check /data1/mongodb/log/mongod.log -file.. What it says when you try to start mongod. Can mongod create that /var/run/mongod/mongod.pid -file?

Comment: I have updated the complete error in the question, this is what i see in the logs now 
`2021-05-21T15:10:40.688-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { processManagement: { fork: true }, systemLog: { destination: "file", path: "/data1/mongodb/log/mongod.l
og" } }
2021-05-21T15:10:40.689-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock Resource temporarily unavailable. Is a mo
ngod instance already running?, terminating`

Comment: Remove that lock file /data/db/mongod.lock and restart mongod. That file exists only when the mongod -process is running and if the process is terminated suddenly, it is not removed and at the next start mongod "thinks" that there is still a process running

Comment: I tried still the same error in `Unable to lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock Resource temporarily unavailable. Is a mo ngod instance already running?, terminating`

Comment: Say at the command line  "pgrep mongod"  if you get number value, then there is mongod running with that process id...